# Servlet is not working in Server AWS

Tags: java, mysql, database

Below given code was working fine in localhost but, when I try to run in server servlet throws blank page, if I remove the Database code in servlet it is working.
I want to run the code with database query as given below,

```
package com.example.servelet;

import com.example.bydhrms.DBConnector;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author ramkumarpr
 */
public class Validation extends HttpServlet {

     Connection DBConnection;   
   String isValidCount,userType,userId,tenantId;
   HttpSession session;
   //Tenant Part

   String tenantUserId, TenantName;
   Statement stm;
   ResultSet resultQuery;
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // Database Connection and Database Logics  
        DBConnection=DBConnector.DatabaseConnection();
         stm=(Statement) DBConnection.createStatement();

         resultQuery=stm.executeQuery("SELECT "
                                    + "user_id as userID, "
                                    + "user_type as userType,"
                                    +"tenant_id as tenantId,"
                                    + "COUNT(user_id) as userCount "
                                    + "From bhi_m_users");

        while(resultQuery.next())
        {
             isValidCount=resultQuery.getString("userCount");
             userType=resultQuery.getString("userType");
             userId=resultQuery.getString("userID");
             tenantId=resultQuery.getString("tenantId");
            out.println(isValidCount);
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         try {
             processRequest(request, response);
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Validation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         try {
             processRequest(request, response);
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Validation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: and what errors do you have logged?

Comment: -------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2016/08/31 03:25:01 [warn] 2729#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11

Comment: this thing i found in error log

Comment: This is just a warning. You should share the whole stacktrace. Also, share the DBConnector class.

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)

Comment: in server log i found that sql connection timeout how to resolve this

Comment: @MugunthanKumar The application is not able to connect to database. Where is the database located? Are you using the correct host and port while connecting to the Database?

Comment: database is located in AWS console RDS this is working fine when iam run the code in local but not in Server

Answer (score -2):

Check your logs. That might tell you what the actual error is.

I guess it is your SQL. You are using an aggregate function COUNT. Shouldn't you be using a GROUP BY clause?

You might also want to close the connection and statement objects at the end.

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSock‌​etImpl.java:345) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPl‌​ainSocketImpl.java:2‌​06) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocket‌​Impl.java:188) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)